# How to encode/decode complex number to bitstream in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, compression, complex-numbers, bitstream

How to compress a complex number like `0.0332815625326639 + 0.000694052654051097i` into a bit stream and then decode it to get back the same number?

Answer (score 0):

To **generate the bitstream**, you can use the following approach:

1. Separate real and imaginary part.
2. Convert the number into its hexadecimal representation with `num2hex` and use each character as one row (transpose it with `.'`).
3. Convert each row to a decimal with `hex2dec`. This is needed for the next step.
4. Create the binary representation for each decimal with `dec2bin`. We need to set a minimal length of 4 since one character in hex occupies 4 bits.
5. Put the values of each row after each other. Now we have converted the hex-string into its binary representation of length 64.
6. Append the imaginary part after the real part which gives us a bitstream of length 128.

To **decode the bitstream** and get the number back, you can reverse the steps above:

1. Split the bitstream in two junks of length 64. The first is the real part (`1:64`), the second represents the imaginary part (`65:128`).
2. Reshape the string to form rows of four characters.
3. Convert the rows to a decimal number with `bin2dec`.
4. Convert the decimal numbers to their hex-representation with `dec2hex`.
5. Convert the hexadecimal string back to the original number with `hex2num`.
6. Use `complex` to get a complex number consisting of the real and imaginary part. You could use `realpart+imagpart*i` as well.

---

**Now let's see the code for all of that:**

```
function the_demo

x = 0.0332815625326639 + 0.000694052654051097i;

bitstream = cb_encode(x)
value = cb_decode(bitstream)

check = x-value    % see if we succeeded


function bin = cb_encode(x)
a1 = dec2bin(hex2dec(num2hex(real(x)).'),4);
a2 = dec2bin(hex2dec(num2hex(imag(x)).'),4);
bin = [reshape(a1.',1,[]),reshape(a2.',1,[])];

function y = cb_decode(bin)
b1 = reshape(bin(1:64),4,[]).';
b1 = hex2num(dec2hex(bin2dec(b1)).');
b2 = reshape(bin(65:128),4,[]).';
b2 = hex2num(dec2hex(bin2dec(b2)).');
y = complex(b1,b2);
```

Running this, gives the following output:

```
>> the_demo
bitstream =
00111111101000010000101001000111111011010100011001101111101000000011111101000110101111100010001010111001101101011000000000110010
value =
   0.0333 + 0.0007i
check =
     0
```